# How can I assign a Swift struct by reference?

Tags: swift, struct, reference, cgrect

As we know, in Swift, classes are reference objects whereas structs other data-types are value types. I'm trying to get the reference of a CGRect into a variable so I can change its value with a shorter name. Is there a way to achieve this? Attempting with an Objective-C or C++ pointer syntax is of no use here :(

```
let reference = someView.frame
frame = ...
```

If I stay at the view level it's ok because it's a reference type, but I want to include the frame in the reference.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
func pointerTo<T>(inout object: T) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T> { 
    return withUnsafeMutablePointer(&object) {UnsafeMutablePointer<T>($0)}
}
```

Comment: Isn't this considered escaping the pointer and thus undefined behaviour, even if it works? This could actually be dangerous beyond the regular unsafe stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't really want to work with references... I could be wrong, and you might have a good reason for wanting a reference. But looking at what you are trying to do, this might be a better approach:

1. Assign the `frame` that you want to work with to a variable:

   `var workingFrame = someView.frame`
2. Work with the copy, making any changes that you want to make:

   `workingFrame = someNewRect`
3. Update `someView.frame` to the new value:

   `someView.frame = workingFrame`

There is, technically, a way to deal directly with pointers to memory addresses, but unless you have an amazingly good reason for going there, I think that most people would recommend that you avoid it.

[Edit:]

If you really want to try to work with pointers to memory addresses, then you may want to look at `UnsafePointer<T>`, `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`, `unsafeBitCast:` and `unsafeAddressOf:`. Those types and functions will give you pointers to a struct.

For example, you can get a mutable pointer to an `Int` value like this:

```
let x = 5

let ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(x))
```

Working with values, pointers, and memory addresses this way is discouraged, but yes, it is possible.

However, using `unsafeAddressOf` converts the `Int` to a class, so even that isn't really a pointer to the original struct. You may end up needing to initialize an `UnsafeMutablePointer`, allocate memory for it, and then assign a value to that memory. Then you can perform operations on the data at that memory address. Check out the documentation for `UnsafeMutablePointer` [here.](http://swiftdoc.org/type/UnsafeMutablePointer/)

And if you can give any more detail as to what, precisely, you are trying to do, there may be a more elegant solution. Swift does not make it easy to work with pointers, but it often provides other tools that allow you to accomplish what you need in a different way.

Comment: I'm afraid my explanation about the issue was over simplified. I really really want a pointer to a struct. 
I've been rattling my brains for ways to do it, even through a inout parameter in a function, but there doesn't seem to be a way... :'(
I can't believe the language won't let you have pointers to any data types. It's crazy....

Comment: I edited my answer to try and point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm testing your code on Swift 2.1 playground and it throws EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Comment: unsafeAddressOf() seems to only work with classes. Tried your code with Int and it crashes, but not with an UIView. This seems most absurd, since with classes there is not much need for pointers since they're reference-types.